# PostgreSQL ERROR: relation "XXX" does not exist and unsure why

Tags: postgresql, relation

I run my code and get the error in PostgreSQL. I have created multiple tables and the first seems to work while the others don't.

```
create table people (
    id              serial,
    family_names    text,
    given_names     text,
    displayed_names text,
    email_address   text,
    primary key (id)
);

create table users (
    userid              integer,
    website             text,
    date_registered     date,
    gender              GenderValue,
    birthday            date,
    password            text,
    portrait            integer,
    
    primary key (userid),
    foreign key (userid) references people(id),
    foreign key (portrait) references photos(photoid)
);

create table photos (
    photoid             serial,
    title               TitleValue,
    date_uploaded       date,
    date_taken          date,
    description         text,
    technical_details   text,
    safety_level        safetyLevel,
    visibility          visibilityLevel,
    owns                integer,

    primary key (photoid),
    foreign key (owns) references users(userid)
);
```

Comment: `users` references `photos`, which hasn't been created yet, so the `CREATE TABLE users` fails. Same goes for `photos`.

Comment: Just, create the tables withouth fks,after create the fks in a different commands.